# flask-login without flask-sqlalchemy or ORM

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql, flask-login

I am currently using flask-login in my application for user login session management. I am using flask-sqlalchemy, so all working ok.
Because of my previous sql experience, I am not fan of ORM. I like to use SQL directly. May be it is because of my not sound knowledge in ORM. Anyways, my question is- is there any way I can use flask-login without ORM/flask-sqlalchemy, where I am getting user data by pymysql or MySQL-connector?

I know I can create sessions myself and pop when I logout, but I want to know if there is any way to use flask-login or any other session management library with pymysql?

Comment: flask-login is agnostic to the way you store and retrieve users, [it doesn't even mention sqlalchemy in requirements](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/requirements.txt). You can use whatever storage and whatever DB driver/engine/ORM you would like.

Comment: @Fian, but how we will use flask-login without models. Because we have to add UserMixin to let's say User model. If I am not using sqlalchemy, and using say pymysql, then I would not have dbModel class. Also, without model class, how current_user would work. I tried to find about using flask-login without models, but can't find anything.

Comment: Flask-login is just a skeleton which requires from you to just implement a few methods, like [load_user](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) and it'll do many other thing for you. So you can implement those methods without using an sqlalchemy with pymysql and that's all. _can't find anything_ — well, [official example on flask-login's github is not using any ORM](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login), you can just read user's data from a db with pymysql in the `user_loader`, attach those data to a `User` instance and it will work fine.

Comment: @Fian, thanks for your help so far. Sorry, can you give me example of how you will define "User" class. I have defined like below, but obviously that is User model class. I know this is naïve question, but I am right now in learning mode. ``` class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True)
    pwd_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))
    email = db.Column(db.String(256),unique=True) ```

Comment: [Something like that](https://trinket.io/python/67076f326d), this example implements an [Active Record Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). If you've chosen to get rid of an ORM, you'll have to do all SQL-related boilerplate by yourself: create tables, do inserts, updates, deletes and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fian! I am little bit old school, so like to get my hands dirty. Moreover I want to learn all options and then I can use whichever I want to, rather than have to.

Comment: @Jay85 Was your problem solved? If yes, please guide me as well...

Comment: @Mr.President To be honest, i didn't use flask-login in my that app at all and code everything myself with pymysql. But may be I will give a try again to make flask-login to work with pymysql

Comment: @Jay85 Thanks for replying, am stuck with the User class. If you try and succeed, please make a blog or something explaining how you managed that.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following solution. It allows to redefine getting user from request `Authorization` header and use in stateless application.

```
from flask_login import login_required, LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):
  api_key: str = request.headers.get('Authorization')
  if api_key:
    token_type, token = api_key.split()
    print("token_type:" + token_type)
    if token_type == "JWT" and token:
        decoded_token: dict = decode_token(token)
        username = decoded_token['identity']
        user: User = get_user(username)
        return user
  return None
```

So if your endpoint is allowed to be used only by authorized users, `@jwt_required` or `@login_required` annotations can be used with method.

Be sure that **route annotation is the first** among others to guarantee correct work of other annotations; your endpoint can be look like:

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@roles_required(['Admin'])  # optional
def list_users():
   return list[]  # your code here
```

Here is another one annotation mentioned, `@roles_required`, it is not obligatory of course. Since Flask user management requires you to use ORM, you can overcome that by defining your own `@roles_required` annotation, see example [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/421#issuecomment-472735960).